# U+2299 (circled dot operator) preceded by U+FE4F (wavy low line) appear larger on Firefox for Windows

Tags: html, windows, firefox, unicode

Consider the following HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Smileys</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Smiley 1: &#x2299;_&#x2299;</p>
    <p>Smiley 2: &#x2299; &#xfe4f; &#x2299;</p>
    <p>Smiley 3: &#x2299;&#xfe4f;&#x2299;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

(See output at http://jsfiddle.net/teVrP/)

See output here:

Smiley 1: ⊙_⊙

Smiley 2: ⊙ ﹏ ⊙

Smiley 3: ⊙﹏⊙

The above code is trying to display three smileys where the
Unicode character U+2299 (CIRCLED DOT OPERATOR) is used for each
eye.

The right eye in the third smiley appears larger than the other
eyes when this HTML is rendered using Firefox 22.0.

In fact, whenever U+2299 (CIRCLED DOT OPERATOR) is immediately preceded
by U+FE4F (WAVY LOW LINE), the circled dot operator appears
larger. This can be seen using this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Circled dot operator</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <p>&#x2299; &#xfe4f;&#x2299; &#x2299;&#xfe4f; &#x2299;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

(See output at: http://jsfiddle.net/L76Q8/)

See output here:

⊙ ﹏⊙ ⊙﹏ ⊙

When the above code is rendered using Firefox 22.0 for Windows, the second
circled dot operator appears larger than the rest.

Screenshots of both pages as rendered on Firefox for Windows:

[image: Smileys on Firefox for Windows]
[image: Circled dot operator on Firefox for Windows]

On Chrome for Windows though, the pages appear fine:

[image: Smileys on Chrome]
[image: Circled dot operator on Firefox]

The pages appear fine on Iceweasel 17 for Debian too.

Why does U+2299 (circled dot operator) preceded by U+FE4F (wavy low line) appear larger on Firefox for Windows? How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Not reproduceable in Firefox 23.0 (Win 7). Could be a bug in Firefox 22.0 that has now been fixed. Could also depend on font settings. (It shouldn’t, but it could.)

Comment: I could successfully reproduce the issue in Firefox 23.0 on Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit Operating System.

Comment: On my Linux system (64-bit, Firefox 23, not that it should matter), it appears even worse, the "wavy low line" appears higher than the circles.

Comment: @Susam, which font have you got as the default font in Firefox? Does the problem appear in other fonts too, if you set font on the page?

Comment: I was now able to reproduce the issue in Firefox 23.0 by setting the default font to Times New Roman (the factory default; I had it set to Cambria).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I have "Times New Roman" set as the default font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second circled dot appears in a different font than the first one. On my Firefox, the first one appears in Segoe UI Symbol, whereas the wavy low line and the second circled dot appear in SimSun. Your browser may use other fonts, but the basic issue is the same. I used the [Font Information](https://addons.mozilla.org/fi/firefox/addon/fontinfo/?src=api) extension to Firefox to check what fonts are really used:

[image: screenshot about using Font Information]

It seems that U+FE4F WAVY LOW LINE somehow makes Firefox use the same fallback font for the next character as it has used for the U+FE4F, in some cases.

One workaround is to insert U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE between the characters: `&#x2299;&#xfe4f;&#xfeff;&#x2299;`. But this is rather awkward.

A better approach is to declare `font-family` for the element containing the string so that the value contains a font that has a glyph for U+2299 CIRCLED DOT OPERATOR. This should make Firefox use the same font both occurrences, since it won’t need to use its backup fonts. Something like the following should handle the issue on Windows:

```
<style>
.smiley { font-family: Segoe UI Symbol, Lucida Sans Unicode }
</style>
<span class=smiley>&#x2299;&#xfe4f;&#x2299;</span>
```

However, if the problem exists on other platforms, too, you might need to write a longish list of [fonts containing the circled dot](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2299/fontsupport.htm).

There is a related problem, mentioned in a comment by @hvd: the wavy long line might appear in an odd shape, especially if it is taken from a font different from one containing the circled dot. A mix of fonts may be acceptable in a string of special characters, but it comes with risks: the glyphs, being from different fonts, might be stylistically incompatible. To deal with this, you might need to consider a fairly complicated font usage problem.

Comment: I am curious to know how you figured the individual fonts used for the first circled dot and the second circled dot.

Comment: I was using the [Font Finder](http://bendodson.com/projects/browser-extensions/) extension to Firefox. As far as I know, it’s the only commonly available tool that lets you see the exact fonts that a browser is actually using for some piece of text (as opposite to just showing `font-family` declarations).

Comment: The Font Finder extension shows 'serif' as the font being rendered: http://imgur.com/HOfC6XA. How did you manage to see 'Segoe UI Symbol' or 'SimSun' as the fonts using Font Finder? I selected a character in the page, right clicked, selected 'Font Finder' and then clicked 'Analyze selection'.

Comment: @SusamPal, I think you are using some different software. I’ve edited the answer to contain a screenshot and a reference to the Font Finder extension (by Ben Dodson) I’me using.

Comment: I got the extension from the link you've provided: http://bendodson.com/projects/browser-extensions/. I installed the extension from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/font-finder/. The screenshots at these links seem similar to what I posted. Could you please check this link once and ensure it is the right one, or provide me a direct link to the download page of the extension you are using?

Comment: Oops! So sorry! I used the Font Information add-on (by Jonathan Kew) and confused the two add-ons with each other. (I had them both installed. The Font Information, or Fontinfo, add-on adds a “Show Fonts in Selection” item in the context menu for right click as well as a “Fonts” pane, showing all fonts on the page, into the Page Info window. And it is the tool for determining the *actual* font, as opposite to e.g. Font Finder, which just analyzes the CSS settings.)

Comment: Thanks! The [fontinfo](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fontinfo/) extension [worked for me](http://imgur.com/ZAc4tbO).